# Error while VBA adding IF formula in validation list

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

When i try to add an IF formula via vba code, i get an "application-defined or object-defined" error. I have checked all my references and they appear to be correct. The sheet is not protected. Just clueless about this error and any help is much appreciated.

```
    With Range("C3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=IF(B3="""","""",'Sheet3'!$A$1:$A$2)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Update: I am getting an error on the ".Add" codeline when i debug.

Comment: Could you try if it works if you remove the `Type:=`, `AlertStyle:=`, `Operator:=` and `Formula1:=` ? Dont remove what is after them, just remove these parts.

Comment: @Moacir If you remove everything, there is an error message that [it is not optional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/validation-add-method-excel). Because Type is required. And when Operator is x1Between, formula2 needs to be specified

Comment: @danieltakeshi I was under the impression that, since the first field is Type, the second field is AlertStyle, etc, it would be redundant to have to name it when you fill that fields. Thanks

Comment: Works absolutely fine on my test. Check `Sheet3` exists and `C3` isn't protected

Comment: Neither of the above worked.

Comment: Does `Sheet3` exist in the workbook you're applying the data validation to? As you're `Range` is not explicitly defined, make sure it is going into the correct workbook. Would suggest replacing with `With ThisWorkbook.Range("C3").Validation`

Comment: @Tom Yes, the sheet exists. After adding your suggestion, i get another error "Method or data member not found" and ".Range" is highlighted.

Comment: Sorry forgot the sheet `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("C3").Validation`

Comment: @Tom I had added the sheet name as well. Still back to the same error. I'm about to pull all my hair out now :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155084/discussion-between-marv-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your formula to `Formula1:="=IF(COUNTBLANK(B3)=1,"""",'Sheet3'!$A$1:$A$2)"` if you are looking for empty cell in `B3`. If it helps there is no error if `B3` is not an empty cell..